# s2i does not create service

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

After deploying ocp3.11 with all-in-one mode, creating application with s2i for registry.redhat.io/jboss-webserver-3/webserver31-tomcat8-openshift:1.2 failed with no service is created.
The steps I used is described in this link:
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_web_server/3.1/html-single/red_hat_jboss_web_server_for_openshift/index#Create-an-OpenShift-application-using-existing-maven-binaries

I installed ocp3.11 on rhel 7.6, no error happened during installation.

I setup docker external registry, it works.

I changed /etc/origin/master/master-config.yaml file, change internalRegistryHostname:docker-registry.default.svc:5000 to my external registry.

After processing s2i for jws31, pod can be startup, but there is no svc with oc get svc.

I checked the dc, found no ports is defined in the dc, but don't know why there is no ports in dc, if there is no ports, I doubt there will be no svc created.

dc is:

```
apiVersion: apps.openshift.io/v1
kind: DeploymentConfig
metadata:
  annotations:
    openshift.io/generated-by: OpenShiftNewApp
  creationTimestamp: 2019-04-12T09:20:44Z
  generation: 2
  labels:
    app: myjws
  name: myjws
  namespace: jws-tomcat
  resourceVersion: "162555"
  selfLink: /apis/apps.openshift.io/v1/namespaces/jws-tomcat/deploymentconfigs/myjws
  uid: 3fbc2413-5d04-11e9-aef5-080027a7340f
spec:
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    app: myjws
    deploymentconfig: myjws
  strategy:
    activeDeadlineSeconds: 21600
    resources: {}
    rollingParams:
      intervalSeconds: 1
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
      timeoutSeconds: 600
      updatePeriodSeconds: 1
    type: Rolling
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        openshift.io/generated-by: OpenShiftNewApp
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: myjws
        deploymentconfig: myjws
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: master311.example.com:5555/jws-tomcat/myjws@sha256:5c65d07aba3ba4e1946a92198588d2d30c5eaef9ea7fe2c209b4db4479e2d130
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: myjws
        resources: {}
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  test: false
  triggers:
  - type: ConfigChange
  - imageChangeParams:
      automatic: true
      containerNames:
      - myjws
      from:
        kind: ImageStreamTag
        name: myjws:latest
        namespace: jws-tomcat
      lastTriggeredImage: master311.example.com:5555/jws-tomcat/myjws@sha256:5c65d07aba3ba4e1946a92198588d2d30c5eaef9ea7fe2c209b4db4479e2d130
    type: ImageChange
status:
  availableReplicas: 1
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: 2019-04-12T09:20:52Z
    lastUpdateTime: 2019-04-12T09:20:52Z
    message: Deployment config has minimum availability.
    status: "True"
    type: Available
  - lastTransitionTime: 2019-04-12T09:20:53Z
    lastUpdateTime: 2019-04-12T09:20:53Z
    message: replication controller "myjws-1" successfully rolled out
    reason: NewReplicationControllerAvailable
    status: "True"
    type: Progressing
  details:
    causes:
    - type: ConfigChange
    message: config change
  latestVersion: 1
  observedGeneration: 2
  readyReplicas: 1
  replicas: 1
  unavailableReplicas: 0
  updatedReplicas: 1
```

svc should be created so that route can be exposed.